# Подсчитать количество вхождений определенных слов на странице html с помощью Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Обучающий курс подкинул следующую задачу:
Мы сохранили страницу с википедии про языки программирования и сохранили по адресу https://online.hse.ru/pluginfile.php/604906/question/questiontext/1341438/1/789274/task_7_2_2.html
На всякий случай: ссылка на тот же самый текст прямо из Википедии:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F
Скачайте её с помощью скрипта на Питоне и посчитайте, какой язык упоминается чаще Python или C++ (ответ должен быть одной из этих двух строк). Необходимо просто подсчитать количество вхождений слова Python или C++ как подстроки.
Я написала следующий код:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
response = urlopen("https://online.hse.ru/pluginfile.php/604906/question/questiontext/1341004/1/789274/task_7_2_2.html")
html = response.read().decode('utf-8')
subs1 = 'Python'
subs2 = 'C++'
cnt1 = html.count(subs1)
cnt2 = html.count(subs2)
print('Количество упоминаний Python', cnt1)
print('Количество упоминаний C++', cnt2)
```

У меня выдает количество упоминаний по обоим словам по нолям. Подозреваю, что это происходит потому, что я считала html код страницы, а не ее содержание. А как считать содержание, не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: а с ссылкой на википедию получается? код рабочий. Ссылка, которая указана в коде приводит на страницу с авторизацией. Нужна ли рутина для авторизации перед переходом по ссылке? Обратите внимание на то, что содержит `response`. Просто выведете содеражание в командную строку.

Comment: Код рабочий. По ссылке указанных слов просто нет.

Comment: Да, Dmitry, Вы были правы. Когда просто взяла ссылку на страницу в Википедии, а не ссылку с образовательного ресурса, все сработало. Проблемы возникли именно из-за необходимости авторизации. Это стало очевидным, когда я по Вашему совету вывела содержание response с обеих ссылок в командную строку. Спасибо большое.